# OSError: Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm' in spaCy when running script in Python IDE

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to run a Python script in Python's built-in IDE (IDLE) that uses the spaCy library, and I'm running into an issue where it can't seem to find the 'en_core_web_sm' model.

Here's the error I'm seeing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\Diss\Latent Dirichlet Allocation - Topic Modelling.py", line 11, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=['parser', 'ner'])
  File "C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 51, in load
    return util.load_model(
  File "C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 472, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I have already downloaded the model using the command python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm, and it works fine when I use it in a Python shell, but I get this error when I try to run my script in the Python IDE.

I'm using Python 3.11.4 and spaCy 3.6.0.

Any ideas on how I might resolve this issue? Thank you in advance for your help!

Verified the installation of the en_core_web_sm model using python -m spacy validate. The model was successfully validated.

Checked the PYTHONPATH and sys.path to ensure that the Python environment has access to the necessary libraries.

Tried loading the model with the full name 'en_core_web_sm' instead of the shortcut 'en'.

Attempted to run the script in the command line, ensuring that the script is run with the same Python interpreter where the model is installed.

Recommended using Anaconda to manage Python environments and packages.

Suggested using a different IDE like PyCharm, and ensured that the correct Python interpreter is used.

Checked the version of Python and spaCy being used.

However, despite all these steps, the issue still persists. It seems that the Python script cannot find the 'en_core_web_sm' model when running in IDLE or other IDEs, even though the model is installed and can be loaded in a Python shell. This issue might be due to the specific configuration of Python environments or IDEs on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the model at runtime to ensure it is present. For this, you can wrap the creation of the model in a function like this one:

```
import spacy


def create_spacy_model() -> spacy.Language:
    spacy_model_name = 'en_core_web_sm'
    try:
        return spacy.load(spacy_model_name)
    except OSError:
        print(
            "Downloading spaCy model for (don't worry, this will only happen once)",
            file=sys.stderr
        )
        from spacy.cli import download
        download(spacy_model_name)
        return spacy.load(spacy_model_name)
```